# Delphi TIdTcpServer get POST parameters sent by browser

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

I am developing a simple Web Server to communicate with my Web App which runs in a browser.

I managed to create a IdTcpServer and get the RequestHeaders submitted by the browser.
I don't know how it's possible to get POST parameters of the form.

here is my code so far:

```
procedure TMyServer.WebServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
    RawData: String;
    TRequestHeader: TStringList;
begin
    TRequestHeader := TStringList.Create;

    // GET Request Headers
    RawData := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
    while RawData <> '' do
      begin
        TRequestHeader.Add(RawData);
        RawData := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
      end;

    // How To get POST or GET Parameters of the HTML form?
    // ...

    // Respond to the Client
    Respond(...);

    TRequestHeader.Free;
end;
```

Comment: The whole (simple) HTTP request is a single "text" document. The header and the content part is only separated by an empty line. What you should have in your TStringList at the end is the whole request, not just the headers. I am not sure how the Indy component works, but might happen that you need to continue reading the socket until it is ended. Then you should parse what you got. There is a quite large set of RFCs that describe the HTTP request, but you will find simple examples too on the web.

Comment: However, unless you want to learn this part, you should not take this path. Spinning up a python or node webserver for such testing purposes in far easier than implementing your own.

Comment: Indy has a TIdHTTPServer (and a TIdCustomHTTPServer). If you are going down that route, I strongly recommend you to use the most suitable object for the task. Web communication is done via HTTP(S), not plain TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the request headers, you need to analyze them to know whether a message body even exists, and in what format it is encoded in so you can read it properly (see [RFC 2616 section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4)), eg:

```pascal
procedure TMyServer.WebServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
end;

procedure TMyServer.WebServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ReqLine, Value: String;
  I: Integer;
  Size: Int64;
  TRequestHeader: TIdHeaderList;
begin
  TRequestHeader := TIdHeaderList.Create;
  try
    // GET Request Line ...
    ReqLine := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;

    // TODO: parse ReqLine as needed to extract HTTP version, resource, and query params ...

    // GET Request Headers ...
    repeat
      Value := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
      if Value = '' then Break;
      TRequestHeader.Add(Value);
    until False;

    // alternatively:
    // AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Capture(TRequestHeader, '', False);

    // get POST or GET data ...

    Value := TRequestHeader.Values['Transfer-Encoding'];
    if (Value <> '') and (not TextIsSame(Value, 'identity')) then
    begin
      repeat
        Value := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;

        I := Pos(';', Value);
        if I > 0 then begin
          Value := Copy(Value, 1, I - 1);
        end;

        Size := StrToInt64('$' + Trim(S));
        if Size = 0 then begin
          Break;
        end;

        // read specified number of bytes as needed ...

        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn; // read CRLF at end of chunk data
      until False;

      // read trailer headers
      repeat
        Value := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
        if (Value = '') then Break;
        // update TRequestHeader as needed...
      until False;  
    end
    else
    begin
      Value := TRequestHeader.Values['Content-Length'];
      if Value = '' then
      begin
        // respond with 411 error
        Exit;
      end;

      Size := StrToInt64(Value);

      // read specified number of bytes as needed ...
    end;

    // process request as needed, based on the value of
    // ReqLine, TRequestHeader.Values['Content-Type'], etc ...

    // Respond to the Client
    Respond(...);
  finally
    TRequestHeader.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, Indy has a `TIdHTTPServer` component that handles the hard work of implementing the HTTP protocol for you (which is not as trivial a task as you think it is). You should not be using `TIdTCPServer` for this.

You can assign a handler to the `TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet` event and use the provided `ARequestInfo` and `AResponseInfo` parameters as needed. The request headers will be in the `ARequestInfo.RawHeaders` property, and various sub-properties (`ARequestInfo.ContentType`, `ARequestInfo.ContentLength`, etc). The `GET`/`POST` data will be in the `ARequestInfo.QueryParams`, `ARequestInfo.FormParams`, and `ARequestInfo.PostStream` properties accordingly, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMyServer.WebServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  // use ARequestInfo.RawHeaders and ARequestInfo.QueryParams as needed ...

  if ARequestInfo.CommandType = hcPOST then
  begin
    if IsHeaderMediaType(ARequestInfo.ContentType, 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') then
    begin
      // use ARequestInfo.FormParams as needed ...
    end
    else begin
      // use ARequestInfo.PostStream as needed ...
    end;
  end else
  begin
    // process GET/HEAD requests as needed ...
  end;

  // Respond to the Client, by populating AResponseInfo as needed ...
end;
```